Why is "const char * const" not used as input string argument for a function in C?
Here is a useful reminder about pointers in C:
int       *      mutable_pointer_to_mutable_int;
int const *      mutable_pointer_to_constant_int;
const int *      mutable_pointer_to_constant_int;
int       *const constant_pointer_to_mutable_int;
int const *const constant_pointer_to_constant_int;
const int *const constant_pointer_to_constant_int;

Now, let's say I have a function do_something that takes a string as input. The string will not be modified. I would write something like this:
void do_something(char const* const string);

Here's the thing: when looking at API code provided by microcontroller manufacturers (which is supposed to be well written), in such a case, I rarely see the type char const * const used as an input type. Instead, they typically write char const* string or const char* string.
Is there a specific reason for this?
Wouldn't it be cleaner to make the pointer itself const as well?
Thank

The top-level const has no meaning to the caller. It wouldn't be able to observe that the callee modifies its parameter anyway. Therefore the top-level const is completely ignored so that the declarations are equivalent.

It doesn't matter.  Consider void foo(int x) versus void bar(const int x).  This tells you that the implementation of bar does not change the (local to it) variable x and foo maybe does....but you don't care.

"constifying" the parameter has no effect whatsoever for the caller. You do not have double sqrt(const double) ... and even if you had, for the caller it would be essentlialy the same double x = 3.14; const double y = 2.71828; sqrt(x) /*x unchanged*/; sqrt(y) /*y unchanged*/;

The explanation for all this is that parameters are passed by value, not by reference. So even if the function assigns the parameter, it has no effect on the caller's variable.

But the object that the pointer points to is not copied. So you need the second const to indicate that it will not modify that object.

"(which is supposed to be well written)" Who told you that? No, code from MCU manufacturers are not really very well written all the time. The code I work with has lots of unused parameters, uses uint32_t instead of pointers, use signed integer constants with unsigned variables and generally use lots of dirty little hacks here and there.

@Gerhardh speaks the truth, in fact I have yet to see well-written code from any MCU manufacturer. I have seen completely bugged and hopeless code countless of times though...

(For example, ask yourself if the MCU you are using right now has a chunk of at least some 4 bytes set aside at address 0 and writing to that address would result in a software fault exception as your C code is obviously accessing a null pointer. No? Now do you think the people who made that MCU have a clue about beginner-level C programming, if they don't even know of something that basic? Or did they rather insist on putting live I/O registers(!!!), reset vectors or some "zero page RAM" at address zero, completely oblivious about the C language?)

Let's look at a simpler case first.
Given
void do_something1( int i ) { ... }

void do_something2( const int j ) { ... }

The following applies:

i is an object of type int.
j is a constant object of type int.

So,

do_something1 would be allowed to modify i, and the following is valid:
void do_something1( int i ) {
   ++i;  // ok
   printf( "%d\n", i );
}


do_something2 would be not allowed to modify string2, and the following is invalid:
void do_something2( const int j ) {
   ++j;  // ok
   printf( "%d\n", j );
}



Keep in mind that parameters are local to their function, so changes to them have no effect in the caller. So making the parameter const only serves to shackle the writer of the function. The benefits of doing so are elusive to me.

The same applies in your code.
Given
void do_something3( char const *s ) { ... }

void do_something4( char const * const t ) { ... }

The following applies:

s is a pointer to a constant object of type char.
t is a constant pointer to a constant object of type char.

So,

do_something3 would be allowed to modify s, and the following is valid:
void do_something3( char const *s ) {
   while ( *s ) {
      putchar( *s);
      ++s;  // ok
   }
}


do_something2 would be not allowed to modify t, and the following is invalid:
void do_something4( char const * const t ) {
   while ( *t ) {
      putchar( *t );
      ++t;  // XXX
   }
}



Again, keep in mind that parameters are local to their function, so changes to them have no effect in the caller. So making the parameter const only serves to shackle the writer of the function. The benefits of doing so are elusive to me.

And also, at least in C, the prototype and function definition are at least somewhat unshackled. void foo(int n); void foo(int const n) { ... } gave no diagnostic with gcc -Wall.


Wouldn't it be cleaner to make the pointer itself const as well?

No, not from the caller's point-of view:
With void do_something(char const* const string); declaration, the 2nd const is noise.
void do_something(char const *string); is simpler, clearer and sufficient for the caller.
That 2nd const is, in effect, an implementation detail of do_something() used in its definition, something that the caller does not care about and so is noise.

You make it sound like making a parameter const (what the OP appears to ask about) is just noise. when it's not. Specifically, it's NOT just noise in void do_something(char const* const string) { ... } vs void do_something(char const* string) { ... }. Could you clarify that you are strictly referring to function declarations that aren't function definitions?

@ikegami True that in the definition of a function,  that 2nd const may have some benefit for the implementer of that function, yet it has no benefit  for the declaration as in OP's declaration example void do_something(char const* const string);.  In my experience I have found when choosing interface design (declaration) vs. the implementation (definition) design, making the interface clearer (names, parameter order, types) is more valuable and productive (top down programming) than the opposite.

@ikegami Further: even using a const parameter in the definition (and no const in the declaration as it is not needed) increases maintenance as the two look different. I avoid a const parameter for that reason.  IMHO, use a const in a definition, when possible, is a style issue - best handled by the group's style guide.

Seems very nonsequitur??? I said it's not clear that what you're saying is only true for declarations that aren't definitions, and that you should clarify that.

The reason why a parameter with a type like const int* const param is confusing is because this is a local copy of the original pointer. The caller shouldn't need to know or care what your function does with that local copy internally - it won't affect the calling code anyway.
Those who typically insist on *const qualified parameters are often intermediately skilled C programmers who have just learnt of the feature. And now they eagerly seek to over-engineer their programs by using it where it isn't needed. A good rule of thumb is to not use various more or less obscure language features just for the heck of it.
In fact there are very few uses of *const qualified pointers - the main valid use of the feature is when you want to allocate pointer tables in true NVM memory in embedded systems. For example a function pointer look-up/state machine etc:
typedef void func_t (void);

func_t* const my_func [n] = { ... }; // this will get allocated in NVM

We really don't want to change function pointer addresses in run-time and with *const we'll be allocating them in flash memory instead of RAM - the latter is usually more valuable.
Another argument is that it's also somewhat common to modify the pointer parameter inside the function. Consider something like a common implementation of strcpy:
char* my_strcpy (char* dst, const char* src)
{
  char* original = dst;

  while(*dst++ = *src++) ... // do some copy implementation and use the `dst` variable in it

  return original;
}



API code provided by microcontroller manufacturers (which is supposed to be well written)

I must have seen such code a hundred times during my 20+ years as microcontroller dev, but I have yet to see well-written code obtained from a silicon manufacturer...

Remember that the parameters of a function are copied into a functions' scope.  The prototype of the function acts like a promise to the function user.  In general the user does not care about function internals.  That being said, the programmer might want to leverage the compiler to enforce certain behaviors within the function. So the prototype declaration does NOT need to match the translation unit definition with regard to const of the parameter itself.
This allows the programmer to make certain hints to the compiler and optimizer on how it can handle the parameter internally, but not clutter
the prototype with meaningless info.
The header file
#ifndef PARAM_SCOPE_H
#define PARAM_SCOPE_H

void const * do_something(char const *my_buf);

#endif // PARAM_SCOPE_H

The translation unit
#include "param_scope.h"
#include <string.h>

void const * do_something(char const * const my_buf)
{
    char another_buf[10];
    memcpy(another_buf, my_buf, sizeof another_buf);
    return my_buf;
}

But if someone comes along later and adds code ahead of the memcpy that accidently modiifies the parameter variable my_buf, the compiler will complain.
